# Why is the sentence "millennial-tinged"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, compounds

I recently came upon with a sentence:

> In her office at Oxford University Press, Paton was drafting a brand new entry for the Oxford English Dictionary. Also in her in-tray when I visited were the **millennial-tinged** usage of “snowflake”, which she had hunted down to a Christian text from 1983 (“You are a snowflake. There are no two of you alike”), and new shadings of the compound “self-made woman”.

I think "millennial" here refer to people of Generation Y. What I fail to understand is why the saying "You are a snowflake. There are no two of you alike" is tinged with millennial features? Does it reflect something specially linked with Generation Y?

Answer (score 1):

Millennials are stereotypically easily offended and very sensitive about anything bad. A "snowflake" or "special snowflake" is a term for somebody with a very delicate ego or who is easily offended - presumably from the fragility of an actual snowflake.

This is different from their 1983 usage which was about snowflakes all being different.

Comment: Can you please cite the source? Thanks.

Comment: @Kris presumably the OED is hunting down the first use of special snowflake wrt millenials

Comment: In that case, this would be a valuable commentary, not an answer perhaps.